# Getting files' tag in AWS S3 bucket

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have a bucket in AWS S3. Lets call it MY_BUCKET.

I would like to iterate the files in this bucket (with Python) and get the tags keys and values.

How do I do it?

Answer (score 2):

**Code to get tags :**

```
s3_resource = boto3.resource('s3')
client = boto3.client('s3')
bucket = s3_resource.Bucket("MY_BUCKET")

for name in bucket.objects.all() :
    response = client.get_object_tagging (
        Bucket = bucket.name,
        Key = name.key
)
print(name.key, response["TagSet"], sep = "\t")
```

First, it retrieves all objects of the bucket using **bucket.objects.all()** and for each object, call **get_object_tagging** which returns dictionary which contains Tagset of the object.

Thanks, Hope it helps !!

Answer (score 1):

Your code would:

- Use [`list_objects_v2()`](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/s3.html#S3.Client.list_objects_v2) to obtain a list of the objects in the bucket
- For each object, call [`head_object()`](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/s3.html#S3.Client.head_object), which returns `metadata`
- Parse `metadata` for the tags

The above functions use the `client` method of calling S3. You could probably do it with the `resource` method too if that is your preference.